# Pode-se armazenar um throw em uma variável?

Tags: php, variáveis, exceção

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
try {
    throw new BadRequestHttpException("Error in Register of your Company");
} catch (BadRequestHttpException $e) {
    throw $e
}
```

Quero saber se é possível e se é uma boa prática utilizar uma variável para armazenar esse a instância desta `Exception` (como está no código abaixo)? Pois precisarei usar mais de uma vez e toda vez que for lançar um novo `throw` não ter que repetir tudo novamente.

```
$badRequest = BadRequestHttpException("Error in Register of your Company");

try {
    throw new $badRequest;
} catch (BadRequestHttpException $e) {
    throw $e
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `throw` não pode porque ele é um *statement* e não um objeto, mas a exceção pode sim, porque não poderia? É um objeto como outro qualquer, como é um texto ou um valor numérico.

Mais uma vez venho dizer que não existe isso de boa ou má prática, existe o certo ou errado para cada situação concreta. O que deseja fazer? Que problema espera resolver? Para isto precisa guardar a exceção em uma variável? Não tem um jeito mais simples fazer? Eu noto que muita gente cria variável sem necessidade de montão.

Se sabe que reutilizará a exceção de forma adequada pode criá-la, mas quase sempre isso não é necessário, e pode ser errado se não entender muito bem o que está fazendo. Na dúvida não faça. Quando a exceção é criada ela carrega uma série de informações sobre a execução e se criar em um lugar e lançar em outro pode ser que as informações estejam defasadas e dar instrumentação errada sobre o que e onde o erro está ocorrendo.

É verdade que quase ninguém sabe usar exceção corretamente e talvez se a informação estiver defasada não faça diferença pra ela, ela nem sabe que existe informação rica sobre o erro ali, mas é uma hipótese e em cima de algo errado, então eu não contaria com isso. E se for para não usar as informações da exceção provavelmente não deveria usá-la.

O problema no seu código é lançar uma exceção dentro de um `catch`, porque faria isto? O motivo para capturar uma exceção é resolver o problema, se não pode fazer isto não capture a exceção, capturar para lançar de novo não faz o menor sentido. Isto está errado.

Duvido que a maioria das pessoas que usam exceção teve a curiosidade de olhar a documentação de [`Exception`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php).

Sem entender profundamente sobre exceção eu limitaria seu uso ao mínimo necessário (em PHP pode ser nunca usar). Exceção é uma das coisas mais complicadas que tem na programação, cheio de detalhes sutis e tem outras formas de obter mais ou menos o mesmo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Infelizmente a documentação do PHP sobre a classe Exception também não ajuda muito.

Comment: @bfavaretto mas pelo menos mostra que essa exceção tem informações importantes e todas suas derivadas terão também e tem um primeiro comentário falando que esses dados são preenchidos no momento da criação e não do lançamento, por isso pode dar ruim se precisar. Um dos motivos que eu falo para as pessoas não usarem exceção porque elas são pesadas (pra transportar ou pra criar) e as pessoas não usam nada disso, então deveriam usar algo mais leve.

Comment: Realmente "O motivo para capturar uma exceção é resolver o problema, se não pode fazer isto não capture a exceção, capturar para lançar de novo não faz o menor sentido. Isto está errado." (Maniero♦, 2019). Da forma como estou fazendo só estou repassando o erro para o usuário, tenho que emitir uma mensagem indicando forma amigavel para o usuário que a sua operação não foi executa com sucesso. Obrigado Maniero, sua resposta me ajudou a entender que não é em todas as situações que devo usar o `try` e o `catch` e que há outras formas de resolver um problema. Thanks.